# Facing issue in IOS app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios8.3

I have to upgrade the app any one help me to solve the errors. This app is developed by others so I can't understand if proper logic is applied.

I am using xcode 6 and simulator iOS 8.3. Maybe they used Three20 framework.

This issue only facing in ios 8 its working proper in ios 7.

> Assertion failure in -[UIPopoverController
>   _presentPopoverFromEdge:ofView:animated:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UIPopoverController.m:880
>
> 2015-06-25 13:54:09.264 [752:11645] Uncaught exception - JS:
>   Unexpected presenting view or presentation edge
>
> 2015-06-25 13:54:09.265 [752:11645] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Unexpected presenting view or presentation edge'
>   *** First throw call stack:

```
(
0   CoreFoundation             0x000000010c556c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

1   libobjc.A.dylib            0x000000010c1efbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation             0x000000010c556aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                 0x0000000109f9b98f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   UIKit                      0x000000010a979f01 -[UIPopoverController _presentPopoverFromEdge:ofView:animated:] + 200
5   UIKit                      0x000000010a97b07a -[UIPopoverController _shimPresentSlidingPopoverAnimated:] + 126
6   UIKit                      0x000000010a97cd91 -[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:] + 70
7                              0x0000000108647313 -[RootViewSplitController willOpenContentUrlPath:] + 339
8   CoreFoundation             0x000000010c44cdec __invoking___ + 140
9   CoreFoundation             0x000000010c44cc42 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 290
10                             0x0000000108757d4b -[TTURLNavigatorPattern invoke:withURL:query:] + 379
11                             0x0000000108757eca -[TTURLNavigatorPattern createObjectFromURL:query:] + 298
12                             0x0000000108753f94 -[TTURLMap objectForURL:query:pattern:] + 260
13                             0x000000010875c03c -[TTBaseNavigator viewControllerForURL:query:pattern:] + 652
14                             0x000000010875b357 -[TTBaseNavigator openURLAction:] + 791
15                             0x0000000108748b4a TTOpenURLFromView + 138
16                             0x000000010873638b -[TTTableViewDelegate tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 283
17  UIKit                      0x000000010a48edc9 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1293
18  UIKit                      0x000000010a48ef0a -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
19  UIKit                      0x000000010a3c162c _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
20  UIKit                      0x000000010a3c14a6 _afterCACommitHandler + 533
21  CoreFoundation             0x000000010c489ca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
22  CoreFoundation             0x000000010c489c00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
23  CoreFoundation             0x000000010c47fa33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
24  CoreFoundation             0x000000010c47f366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
25  GraphicsServices           0x000000010cf43a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
26  UIKit                      0x000000010a39d900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
27                             0x00000001085d1d12 main + 162
28  libdyld.dylib              0x000000010cac3145 start + 1
)
```

---

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: Please add the code at which line it crashes.

Comment: Three20 and iOS8 is not a good combo

Comment: @Rajesh after last line app is not working -->libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb).

Comment: @jasper this app is already developed so i cant change hole thing plz provide some solutions..... thanx .

Comment: Can see the line at which your debugger stop and application crash?

Comment: @RajeshMaurya my app is stop working or crash ---->  0x1085d1d12 <+162>: movl   %eax, -0x14(%rbp)
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,Subcode=0x0)                       ---> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you rename any files outside the XCode. For solving this, remove the files from your bundle and re-import.

This can help you.

Comment: i am not rename any files .........i check this already ...any thing else.....thank's

Comment: in this they used three20 framework do you have nay idea for that ..?its not working for IPAD 8.3 IOS